# How to make three.js rendering compatible with responsive design

Tags: iphone, iframe, responsive-design, three.js

How do I make the rendering using the following three.js code scale as the browser window scales, i.e. the text becomes smaller as the browser window becomes smaller?

Or, can you suggest an alternative approach? I tried using an iframe (with appropriate styling code to make the iframe scale as the browser window scales) which references a web page with the three.js rendering. That approach worked for desktop browsers but did not work for an iPhone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="three.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="helvetiker_bold.typeface.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var camera, renderer;
function init3d() {
    var container = document.getElementById('3d');              
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, 747 / 531, 1, 2400 );
    camera.position.set( 0, 300, 900 );
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x606060 );
    scene.add( ambient );
    var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffcc );
    spotLight.position.set( -1000, 2400, 2400 );
    scene.add( spotLight );

    var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( "HELLO", {
        size: 100,
        height: 20,
        curveSegments: 12,
        font: "helvetiker",
        weight: "bold",
        style: "normal",
        bevelThickness: 2,
        bevelSize: 5,
        bevelEnabled: true
    });
    textGeo.computeBoundingBox();   
    var centerOffset = -0.5 * ( textGeo.boundingBox.max.x - textGeo.boundingBox.min.x );

    var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x80a0c0, specular: 0xffffff } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, textMaterial );
    mesh.position.x = centerOffset;
    mesh.position.y = -10;
    var text = new THREE.Object3D();
    text.add( mesh );
    scene.add( text );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );         
    renderer.setClearColor( 0x204060 );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement ); 
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = document.getElementById("3d").offsetWidth /document.getElementById("3d").offsetHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( document.getElementById("3d").offsetWidth, document.getElementById("3d").offsetHeight );
}

window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener("load",init3d,false) : window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload",init3d);
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#339966">
<div style="max-width:747px; max-height:531px; width:100%">
  <div id="3d" style="width:100%"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```